# tryCatch Unit testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test tryCatch code with jest but keep on getting error, currently this is what I've tried

student.js

```
async checkStudentExist(studentName) {
        try {
            const studentExist = await this.StudentRepository.getOne({name: studentName})
            if (studentExist) {
                throw new Error(`Student already exist with the name: ${studentName}`)
            }
            return studentExist
        } catch (error) {
            throw error   
        }
    }
```

student.test.js

```
it('should throw an error if the input name already exist in database', async () => {
    mockGetOne.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(expectedOrganization))
    await studentService.checkStudentExist('john doe')
    expect(mockGetOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({name: 'sample org'})
    expect(studentService.checkStudentExist('john doe')).resolves.toThrowError(new Error(`Organization already exist with the name: john doe`))
})
```

and this is the error I'm getting

```
 FAIL  test/specs/services/student_service.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log src/services/student_service.js:53
      111
    console.log src/services/student_service.js:53
      111

  ● Check if Student exist › should throw an error if the input name already exist in database

    Student already exist with the name: john doe

      55 |             const studentExist = await this.StudentRepository.getOne({name: studentName})
      56 |             if (studentExist) {
    > 57 |                 throw new Error(`Student already exist with the name: ${studentName}`)
         |                       ^
      58 |             }
      59 |             return studentExist
      60 |         } catch (error) {

      at StudentService.checkStudentExist (src/services/student_service.js:57:23)
```

Comment: What is the error you keep getting ?

Comment: Will edit the questions with the error